# Impedir que subdominio redirija a dominio principal en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirección

Ojalá alguien me pueda ayudar.

Tengo este subdominio: `test.anexinet.com`

y me redirige a dominio principal: `anexinet.com`

este es mi .htaccess (del subdominio)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Me gustaría evitar ese redireccionamiento, ya intente varios códigos que provee Wordpress pero nada funciona, ¿alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 1):

Si se cumplen los siguientes requisitos debería funcionar:

1. Tener instalado el Wordpress de `test.anexinet.com` en la carpeta `test` de `public_html`
2. Tener este código en el `.htaccess` de la carpeta `test` mencionada en el punto 1:

   ```
   # BEGIN WordPress

   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /test/
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L]
   </IfModule>

   # END WordPress
   ```

Comment: Hey gracias por la aclaracion,

Eh puesto tu codigo y solo puedo entrar al subdominio en ventanas incognito... pero en ventanas normales del navegador me sigue redirigiendo...  sigo  buscando que hacer, si tienes algun otra idea te o agradezco muchisimo...

Comment: @Conejoconsal si es como dices vas a necesitar limpiar la memoria caché del navegador, puede que tenga datos viejos y por eso no te funcione. Busca esa opción en el menú desarrollo del navegador que estés usando.